# PHP code, remove renaming

Tags: php

If possible please i'd ask a favor, i've been trying to change this it but i haven't succeeded, i wanted to change it in my php file, but no result!

now this script below is a resize script, but it renames my file... i don't need it to do so, can you please see it and tell me how to remove the renaming of the file?

I know it has something to do with : $image->createFile(md5($tempFile)); i tried removing the md5 and still nothing...

Thanks!

```
function setFile($src = null) {
$this->ext = strtoupper(pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if(is_file($src) && ($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG")) {
$this->img_r = ImageCreateFromJPEG($src);
} elseif(is_file($src) && $this->ext == "PNG") {
$this->img_r = ImageCreateFromPNG($src);
} elseif(is_file($src) && $this->ext == "GIF") {
$this->img_r = ImageCreateFromGIF($src);
}
$this->img_w = imagesx($this->img_r);
$this->img_h = imagesy($this->img_r);
}

function resize($largestSide = 100) {
$width = imagesx($this->img_r);
$height = imagesy($this->img_r);
$newWidth = 0;
$newHeight = 0;

if($width > $height){
$newWidth = $largestSide;
$newHeight = $height * ($newWidth / $width);
}else{
$newHeight = $largestSide;
$newWidth = $width * ($newHeight / $height);
}

$this->dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($this->dst_r, $this->img_r, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
$this->img_r = $this->dst_r;
$this->img_h = $newHeight;
$this->img_w = $newWidth;
}

function createFile($output_filename = null) {
if($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG") {
imageJPEG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext, $this->quality);
} elseif($this->ext == "PNG") {
imagePNG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
} elseif($this->ext == "GIF") {
imageGIF($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
}
$this->output = $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext;
}

function setUploadDir($dirname) {
$this->uploaddir = $dirname;
}

function flush() {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

imagedestroy($this->dst_r);
unlink($targetFile);
imagedestroy($this->img_r);

}

}

$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

move_uploaded_file ($tempFile, $targetFile);

$image = new Image();
$image->setFile($targetFile);
$image->setUploadDir($targetPath);
$image->resize(800);
$image->createFile(md5($tempFile));
```

Comment: Hey, i'm sorry, you;re right :/ i kept changing the javascript file and unconsciously i said javascript :/

Comment: Look into the meaning of $_FILES. Your image is saved as a temp file on the server; a new name is needed to store it. Now $_FILES['Fildedata']['temp_name'] is used to do so. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php offers more options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing to

```
$image->createFile('resized_'.$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);


function createFile($output_filename = null) {
    if($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG") {
        imageJPEG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename, $this->quality);
    } elseif($this->ext == "PNG") {
        imagePNG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename);
    } elseif($this->ext == "GIF") {
        imageGIF($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename);
    }
    $this->output = $this->uploaddir.$output_filename;
}
```

Comment: Right, and then remove md5().

Comment: Hey, thanks :) it worked, can you please help me with one more thing, i need to remove the .PNG , .JPG etc... because the name becomes something like : Default.png.PNG

Comment: that is because your function `function createFile()` is adding the extension, that was for the `md5()` filename, simply remove `.'.'.$this->ext` from every line in that function.

Comment: Hey thanks.. well in fact when i remove that extension, it doen't create the image at all...

Comment: make sure you remove exactly how I said. `.'.'.$this->ext`

Comment: Yes i did.. but it doesn't create the file anymore.. if i remove just .$this->ext it works still but there remains the '.' , if i remove that the file won't be created..

Comment: That's what i'm saying, that i did that, and it doesn;t work! it does not create the image!...

Comment: I've updated my answer, that code should work with no problems, unless you changes something someplace else.

Comment: I don't know what to say to you, it doesnt work... and i haven't changed a thing, but anyways, i'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You confuse the file's actual name (`$_FILES['Filedata']['name']`) with the temporary name (`$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']`). The first is the file the client uploaded. The second is a temporary file that the server created one the server's machine. So you have to use the actual, client-side name here.

Answer (score 0):

This will make your day

```
$image->createFile(preg_replace("/\.[^\.]*$/", "", $targetFile));
```